# Cannot validate Twilio webhook signatures for calls from authorized, Connect subaccounts

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

We're using [Twilio Connect](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/connect) to allow our users to connect their Twilio accounts to ours. We provision a number for their subaccount, and set the messaging webhook to POST to our server.

We try to validate the request using the Twilio node library [`validateRequest` method](https://www.twilio.com/blog/how-to-secure-twilio-webhook-urls-in-nodejs) but validation always fails. I think that's because we're passing *our* client secret to validate a request that's coming from our *user's* Twilio account.

How should validate Twilio webhook calls that come from accounts we're authorized to use (but are not our own accounts)?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a permissions thing! There are two permissions available for Twilio Connect Apps -- Read all account data & Charge account for usage! You would only be able to have full autonomy over a users account & subaccounts if you use the "Read all account data" permission when setting up the Connect App.